# Как достать JSON из словаря

Tags: json, swift, swift4

Столкнулся с проблемой
У меня есть словарь в котором хранится мой JSON
Он выглядит так

```
 var dist: [String:Any] = [:]
```

Так выглядит JSON

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"message": "Данные пользователя",
"content": {
    "id": 59,
    "score": 0,
    "level": 1,
    "level_experience": 0,
    "level_up_experience": 24,
    "daily_level_goal": 1,
    "daily_level_completed": 0,
    "daily_tempo": 0,
    "wasted_hours_count": 0,
    "daily_progress": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}}
```

Каким образом мне достать из словаря содержимое этого JSON
Допустим id, level, score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам нужно привести `Any` к другому типу, в вашем случае это будет опять таки `[String:Any]` выглядит это так (один из вариантов):

```
if let json = dict["content"] as? [String: Any] {
    let id = json["id"]
    //и так далее....
    //только учтите значения вы получите типа Any 
    //и их нужно будет приводить к нужному типу
} else {
    print("content isn't json")
}
```

вот [тут](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html) можно прочитать про преведение типов

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать как это сделать, допустим в print как вывести id?

Comment: добавить `print(id)` после `let id = json["id"]`

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы указали, что используете swift 4, я бы рекомендовал сделать через Codable тип, который добавили в swift 4.

1) Объвляем типизированную структу разобора(в идеале, в отдельном файле):

```
struct UserInfo: Decodable {
    let statusCode: UInt
    var message: String? = nil
    var content: Content? = nil
}

struct Content: Decodable {
    let id: UInt
    let score: UInt
    let level: UInt
    let level_experience: UInt
    let level_up_experience: UInt
    let daily_level_goal: UInt
    let daily_level_completed: UInt
    let daily_tempo: UInt
    let wasted_hours_count: UInt
    let daily_progress: [UInt]
}
```

2) В нужном месте, где получили json от сервера:

```
do {
    let userInfo = JSONDecoder().decode(UserInfo.self, from: jsonData)
    print(userInfo.content?.id)
    print(userInfo.content?.level)
    print(userInfo.content?.score)
    print(userInfo.content?.daily_progress)
} catch {
    print("Не верная структура данных")
}
```

Если вы уверены, что сервер вам отдает поле "content" всегда и там не будет null, можете написать без "? = nil"